# Need help for Android project

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Please help me for this Android project. I don't have much experience with Android.
I have an Android project with the UI like this :

Landscape :

[image]

And portrait:

[image]

There are many buttons in the menu (I call it tabbar menu).
When A menu item is selected, I have to show a screen like the images. And when user touch on a control on "View 2" maybe I have to show another screen.
Now I am using only one Activity and trying to using views. I also set
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" for the activity and control orientation by myself. I believe it is not a good design because there are too much views and example when the app is killed by the OS, it is difficult for me to restore app state.

I believe you have more experience than me. So, please suggest me a few solutions about UI design, or what should I do, like using more activity, using fragment (I have never used Fragment)....

Sorry because my English is not really well !
Thanks

Sorry you all, view 1, view 2 actually are Layouts. And the bar menu which I have customized the radio button and put it in a RadioGroup. (Radio group is in scroll view). And I keep View1, View2 in a RelativeLayout.
And about the UI. It is because the requirement from customer. It is like Gmail app on Galaxy tab, but it has the tab bar.

Comment: It's quite difficult to help with you looking only on this images. I think you have to read about fragments and use them in this case: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, for best practices in "Android" UI, see http://developer.android.com/design.  But I would not recommend this site for a complete beginner.  Take some time to get acquainted with basic Android development first, so that you will have the perspective to understand what the [Design](http://developer.android.com/design) pages are talking about.  Build and run some of the sample apps, and read some of the lessons at http://developer.android.com/training.

Now that I've covered the basics:  Are you really sure you want to implement the UI that you have illustrated above, even if it goes against Android UI recommendations?  If so, you are signing up for extra work.

Android already provides an [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) at the top of the display.  If you really want your menu on the side or bottom, then you will have to reinvent what it does yourself.  If that's still your plan, then I recommend using a [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html).

For your broader layout, I agree with [prolink007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427763/prolink007): Your Menu1, View1, and View2 should probably be implemented in 3 Fragments.  You can use LinearLayout again as a container to hold your Fragments.

Answer (score 1):

[`Fragments`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) will solve all your problems here.

There are many great examples and the link i posted will help you get started.

[Here is a similar post with many examples as answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710573/need-a-fragments-example)

Comment: Thank you all : prolink007, Teovald, Ilya Demidov, Sparky. Now , I am using Fragment. And it is really useful.

Answer (score 1):

View1 and View2 sounds like perfect applications for fragments !
Take a look at the documentation, it is not hard.
Also, I think that if you target the latest release of Android, the sdk is able to create a bare split view layout for you that uses fragments. It does not fit what you want to do, but it is a good base to see how to do that kind of things.

Also, the convention for Android is to put the menu bar at the top with the help of the ActionBar Class. Putting it on the side is not necessarily an awful idea though. Especially if your project target tablets. However, try not to fit Android conventions as much as you can : your users are used to these conventions in the Google Apps and all the apps that implement Holo. So adhering to the same interactions principles is a pretty good way to deliver an intuitive experience to your users.

Answer (score 1):

> layout: general layouts
>
> layout-port: layout for widget that must change for portrait orientation
>
> layout-land: layout for widget that must change for landscape orientation

Good luck!